# Swing: taking variables from two private jTextField?ActionPerformed classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm in NetBeans 8.2 and I've constructed a nice jFrame GUI for a Binary-to-Decimal converter, I think I have the code in my two text fields correct but I can't figure out how to access the variables for my Button to perform operations on.

I have 3 method operations called parseBinary, isBinary, and illegal that I want to use to perform operations on my two text fields.
In NetBeans when you code a button the method is locked to private so that's my issue.

I will post all my of code and highlight where my issue is (near the bottom):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Assignment2_gui extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

public static int parseBinary(String binary) throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (!isBinary(binary))
    {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal(binary));
    }
    int power = 0;
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
        {
            decimal += Math.pow(2, power);
        }
        power++;
    }
    return decimal;
}

public static boolean isBinary(String binary)
{
    for (char ch : binary.toCharArray())
    {
        if (ch != '1' && ch != '0')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char illegal(String iChar)
{
    char test = 0;
    char arr[] = iChar.toCharArray();
    for(char cha : arr)
    {
        if (cha != '1' && cha != '0')
        {
            test = cha;
        }
    }
    return test;
}

/**
 * Creates new form Assignment2_gui
 */
public Assignment2_gui()
{
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")



///////// the issue is with this jButton method and the two jTextField methods /////////

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                              

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    JTextField test1 = new JTextField("");
    test1.setText(test1.getText());
}                                           

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    JTextField test2 = new JTextField("");
    test2.setText(test2.getText());
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Assignment2_gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't create components in an ActionListener and expect other parts of code to access the components. You need to create the GUI with all its components first before adding ActionListener code. Start with the Swing tutorial on [Learning Swing With Netbeans IDE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html). The example shows how to create a simple app to do Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion, so the steps would be very similar to what you are attempting.

Comment: An ActionPerformed handler is not the place to be creating a new `JTextField`.  What were you hoping to accomplish by doing this?  And if you thought those `JTextField`s were the variables you needed to access in the handler for your button, it's hopeless anyway: you can't access one method's local variables from another.

Comment: Thank you both. I've taken what I've learned from here and encountered a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922804/how-to-display-a-result-inside-a-jtextfield-after-clicking-a-jbutton