# How to display a "result" inside a jTextField after clicking a jButton?

Tags: swing, jbutton, jtextfield

In this Binary-to-Decimal converter, how do I display the decimal result/exception throw to the 2nd jTextField?

The user inputs a Binary number into the 1st jTextField. Then after clicking the "Convert" button the program should output that number in its Decimal form. Or if there are any illegal characters (anything but 0 or 1) it will display an error message within the jTextField instead.

I already have all of the methods correct and I know they're responding to the "Convert" button correctly because when you input something like "0101b" into the "Binary" jTextField it throws the correct error.

**My issue is** that I don't know how to go about making the result/error display itself within the second jTextField. I'm using a driver method that contains the main method. Any tips are very much appreciated.

EDIT: I believe the issue is within the actionPerformed class. I'm trying to change the value of storeString1 (using setText() / getText()) depending on which tests are passed, but checking them is troublesome too because I'm trying to test a JTextField with an int (parseBinary), a boolean (isBinary), and another int (illegal).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class second extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JLabel enterString1, enterString2;
private JTextField string1, string2;
private JButton click;
private String storeString1 = "";

public second(){
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(450,180);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    enterString1 = new JLabel("Binary: ");
    enterString2 = new JLabel("Decimal: ");
    click = new JButton("Convert");
    string1 = new JTextField();
    string2 = new JTextField();

    enterString1.setBounds(90, 25, 120, 30);
    enterString2.setBounds(90, 60, 120, 30);
    string1.setBounds(210, 25, 200, 25);
    string2.setBounds(210, 60, 200, 25);
    click.setBounds(17,105,400,30);
    click.addActionListener(this);

    add(click);
    add(string1);
    add(string2);
    add(enterString1);
    add(enterString2);
}

public static int parseBinary(String binary) throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (!isBinary(binary))
    {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal(binary));
    }
    int power = 0;
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
        {
            decimal += Math.pow(2, power);
        }
        power++;
    }
    return decimal;
}

public static boolean isBinary(String binary)
{
    for (char ch : binary.toCharArray())
    {
        if (ch != '1' && ch != '0')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char illegal(String iChar)
{
    char test = 0;
    char arr[] = iChar.toCharArray();
    for(char cha : arr)
    {
        if (cha != '1' && cha != '0')
        {
            test = cha;
        }
    }
    return test;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == click) // if the button is clicked, do the following:
    {
        storeString1 = string1.getText();
        int a = parseBinary(storeString1);
        boolean bool = isBinary(storeString1);
        int b = illegal(storeString1);
        string2.setText(storeString1);
    }
}
}
```

This is my main method:

```
public class driver 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    second s = new second();
    s.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: `My issue is that I don't know how to go about making the result/error display itself within the second jTextField.` - then you haven't read the tutorial I provided you with in your last question. There is demo code for you to download and test and play with. It shows how to update the text of a text field in the ActionListener. How is this any different?

Comment: Also, why are you using setBounds()? Swing is designed to be used with layout managers. There is also a section in the tutorial on Layout Managers. Read the tutorial and learn some Swing basics. You can't keep asking a question every time you have a problem. The tutorial is full of Swing basics that will show coding examples. You will also note that the examples rarely use static methods. The conversion/editing methods should be part of your class. Your methods also return values but you never test these values so how do you know if a character is valid or not?

Comment: I have read it, at least the jTextField section, and I was still stuck so I posted this followup question. Also I'm using setBounds() because another tutorial I was following used it. I'm a novice.

Comment: What happened when you downloaded the demo code and tested it? Did you not see how to update the value of a text field with the converted value? Would you not use the same method to update a text field with an error message? We have no idea what part of the code you are confused about.

Comment: I've already specified which part I'm confused about.

Comment: I'm trying to implement something along the lines of `//Parse degrees Celsius as a double and convert to Fahrenheit.
    int tempFahr = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText()))
            * 1.8 + 32);
    fahrenheitLabel.setText(tempFahr + " Fahrenheit");`

Comment: Where? I don't see anywhere in your code where you invoke the setText() method in the ActionListener code? Why do you have an if statement in the listener? Does the demo code have an if statement. Again, I don't see your code looking anything like the demo code. As I told you before you invoke a method, but you never do anything with the value returned from the method, so why do you return a value. I would think you want to take the returned value and update the text field, but I can't read your mind so I'm not sure what you are thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157418/discussion-between-ryan-horner-and-camickr).